# how to read and write files dynamically from sdcard

Tags: android

hi all i used below code dynamically get files from sdcard but it shows force close my intention is when i open the files it must show all directories and files from there i to read and write should be start  help me to solve this problem

```
public void openFile(Context context, File f)
{

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    String type = getMIMEType(f);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), type);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: If the app is force closing it will help in getting an answer to attach a logcat output of the exception being generated.

Comment: Hi laxman, Do you want code which will read and write data to SDcard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not exactly clear what you need, but if your app is crashing, have you checked "LogCat" under "DDMS"?
It will tell you exactly the stacktrace, which will help you understand why your application is crashing.